# USB Mount Fails with no error

Tags: 16.04, usb, mount

I have the following setup:

```
$ uname -a
Linux movieserver 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The issue is this:  I have a large external USB drive connected.  It frequently unmounts.  When this happens, the mount point will usually still be listed in `df -h`.  I then have to `umount -l /big6tb` to get it to go away.  If I then try to mount it again, the command runs with no issues, but it doesn't actually mount.

```
# mount /dev/sde1 /big6tb/
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs           276M   29M  247M  11% /run
/dev/sda1       456G  404G   30G  94% /
tmpfs           1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           276M     0  276M   0% /run/user/1000
root@movieserver:/# umount -l /big6tb/
umount: /big6tb/: not mounted
root@movieserver:/#
```

I have tried updating the list of USB devices with the following:

```
lsusb -v 2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

then:

```
ls -l /dev/sd*
```

The drive is listed there, but continues to not mount.

The only way I've found to kludge fix it is to restart the server, which is idiotic.

Any and all ideas are most appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT: adding info from Waltinator's suggestion.

```
root@movieserver:/usr/local/bin# journalctl /dev/sde1
-- Logs begin at Mon 2018-09-03 04:52:01 EDT, end at Mon 2018-09-03 22:27:03 EDT. --
Sep 03 22:22:43 movieserver kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
Sep 03 22:22:43 movieserver kernel: usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Sep 03 22:25:30 movieserver kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
Sep 03 22:25:30 movieserver kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=25ee
Sep 03 22:25:30 movieserver kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Sep 03 22:25:30 movieserver kernel: usb 1-1: Product: My Book 25EE
Sep 03 22:25:30 movieserver kernel: usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
Sep 03 22:25:30 movieserver kernel: usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Sep 03 22:25:30 movieserver kernel: scsi host13: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
Sep 03 22:25:31 movieserver kernel: scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book 25EE     4004 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Sep 03 22:25:31 movieserver kernel: sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Sep 03 22:25:31 movieserver kernel: sd 13:0:0:0: [sde] Spinning up disk...
Sep 03 22:25:34 movieserver kernel: sd 13:0:0:0: [sde] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
Sep 03 22:25:34 movieserver kernel: sd 13:0:0:0: [sde] 11721043968 512-byte logical blocks: (6.00 TB/5.46 TiB)
Sep 03 22:25:34 movieserver kernel: sd 13:0:0:0: [sde] 4096-byte physical blocks
Sep 03 22:25:34 movieserver kernel: sd 13:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
Sep 03 22:25:34 movieserver kernel: sd 13:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
Sep 03 22:25:34 movieserver kernel: sd 13:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page found
Sep 03 22:25:34 movieserver kernel: sd 13:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
Sep 03 22:25:34 movieserver kernel: sd 13:0:0:0: [sde] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
Sep 03 22:25:34 movieserver kernel: sd 13:0:0:0: [sde] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
Sep 03 22:25:34 movieserver kernel: sd 13:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
```

To clarify, on reboot, device will show as sdb1 and mounts fine.  After it disappears, it'll show up in /dev as sde1 or something similar, and the mount command just doesn't work.  If I run it with -v, it'll literally say that it's mounted, but it isn't.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I won't be specific, but I had similar issues ages ago.  The external drive was 'sleeping'  (energy saving) and didn't want to wake when I later wanted to read data from it (which was often the next day).  I was lazy & didn't try to properly resolve mine, just wrote a script that caused a read of a file from the drive every ~28mins (guess; I forget the timing) so the drive stayed awake... It was a dirty hack, but worked.  The system has since been retired, so I'd be unlikely to find my 'hack' script sorry.

Comment: You can see logs related to `/dev/sde1` with `journalctl /dev/sde1`.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks, I tried that based on your suggestion.  Basically just had it cat the file every 10 minutes, then just for overkill had it write recent timestamp to the file.  Didn't change anything as far as I can tell.  Thing disappeared, and then then i check /dev I see that it's back as sde1 instead of sdb1 as it was after reboot.

Comment: If you `cat` the same file, the file contents may be cached, and thus no actual IO occurs and the device will fall asleep. I can't recall what my script did, except it read a random part of the disk (random file possibly; or random inode/lba/sector - I can't remember; this bit was the bulk of the script) thus it was never in cache.  I recall getting that 'random' part of disk was the only 'trick' in my hack (which is why I didn't want to advise, I can't recall how I got it there, other than it took the most time in working out how...)